# Extracting the key of an array - no duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to create a loop, to output the key in an array - all the objects in the array have the same key, so I want that key once.

However I cannot figure out how to do this, I can only seem to exact every object's key multiple times! It looks like it loops through each object in the array.

How can I extract the key of the array once!

Thanks.

My code looks like:

```
   var obj = array

   var newAryk = []
   Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (k) {
      newAryk.push(k)
   });
```

I'm trying to get the output to look like :

```
['Color', 'qty']
```

My array looks like:

```
    [
      {
        Color: 'Green',
        qty: '3',
      },
      {
        Color: 'Pink',
        qty: '3',
      },
      {
        Color: 'Purple',
        qty: '3',
      }
    ]
```

Comment: It's an array with 3 objects in it, fetch for index 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all objects have the same keys, then just use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) on first array element.

```
var keys = Object.keys(arr[0]);
```

If objects have different keys, then use [Set()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

```
var keys = new Set();

arr.forEach(obj => {
  let objKeys = Object.keys(obj);
  objKeys.forEach(key => keys.add(key));
});

// Convert from Set to Array.
keys = Array.from(keys);
```

**Live Example:**

```js
var arr = [{ Color: 'Green', qty: '3', }, { Color: 'Pink', qty: '3', }, { Color: 'Purple', qty: '3', } ];

var keys = new Set();

arr.forEach(obj => {
  let objKeys = Object.keys(obj);
  objKeys.forEach(key => keys.add(key));
});

// Convert from Set to Array.
keys = Array.from(keys);

console.log(keys);
```